# Raspberry pi no module named socket server

Tags: camera, python-3

I have a strange raspberry pi issue. When I run a python code manually it works perfect but when I run it during startup it gives this error `no module named socket server`. This is the code given below and I have python 3

```
# Web streaming example
# Source code from the official PiCamera package
# http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming

import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server
```

I had to put the file in boot order sequence so I did this

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
```

And then I added this code at the bottom to run on startup

```
sudo python /home/pi/mypyscript.py
```

Where is the mistake? Does socketserver loads at the end. I am using Raspberry Pi zero to control a raspberry Pi camera.

Comment: [bashrc is NOT intended to run scripts](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83774/changing-bashrc-to-run-python-script/83775#83775)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`python` is **never** Python 3 in Debian, even if you have installed Python 3. Python 3 will install as `python3`, and the `python` binary points to Python 2 (see [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)) instead.

In Python 2, the `socketserver` module used to be called [`SocketServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) (note the caps). Changing all references from `socketserver` to `SocketServer` would address that.

You can solve this by either:

- changing the code to support Python 2, or
- running `python3 /home/pi/mypyscript.py` instead of `python /home/pi/mypyscript.py`

It may also be helpful to note Milliways' advice, though that certainly isn't the cause of the error, just a potential pitfall when you do get this working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It started working. I have a small doubt though how can i stop running the code? Do I need to open the file and stop it manually?

Comment: You would probably need to [kill it manually](https://superuser.com/q/446808/655923), @Amit, by finding the correct process and running the kill command from the terminal. If you've run it interactively (i.e. it blocks your console) you can run Ctrl+C; otherwise, if you've run it at startup, you'll have to kill it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically `.bashrc` DOES NOT run until you open a shell, and it runs EVERY TIME you open a shell. It DOES NOT run on startup.

[bashrc is NOT intended to run scripts](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83774/changing-bashrc-to-run-python-script/83775#83775)

Comment: You were correct as crontab did the job. I did `crontab -e` and then adding `@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myscript.py&` at the bottom it started working on reboot.